# Why Uri.parse() does not return valid image uri of an image in the drawable folder?

Tags: android, uri, android-drawable

```
intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        intent.setType("image/jpg");
        //intent.setType("image/*");

        Uri imageUri = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.example.anjuthanm.intenttest/"+R.drawable.test_image);
        //Uri imageUri = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.example.anjuthanm.intenttest/drawable/test_image");

        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imageUri);
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Sent from my app");
        chooser = Intent.createChooser(intent, "Send Image");
        startActivity(chooser);
```

When I run the app it opens the chooser dialog box. When I select Whatsapp it toast appears saying file format not supported. When I choose Evernote, the evernote app opens but the image is show as "7985522.null" (Some random number).

I think the image is not getting parsed into a valid uri.

In the tutorial I follow it seems to work for them. Is there anything wrong in the code?

Comment: R.drawable.test_image does not provide valid path

Comment: you cannot have an absolute path of an image in drawable folder. Its a reference to a file what you get with R.drawble so you have to read it with InputStream and then create a File and get the path

Comment: to be sure you are not making any typo, try: `Uri uri = new Uri.Builder()
                .scheme(ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE)
                .authority(getPackageName())
                .path(String.valueOf(R.drawable.test_image)).build();`

Comment: The `android.resource` scheme is uncommon. Expect problems with many apps.

Comment: @pskink I tried your code. Still getting the same error "File format not supported" in whatsapp.