# mp4 in VideoView

Tags: android, mp4, android-videoview, video-encoding

The original format I had for my video file made it not work for any device, so I ran it through ffmpeg to convert it to a type which would be more compatible. Now, it runs on most devices, but there are still a few that give the error "Cannot play this file"

The command i used to convert it was:

```
ffmpeg -i <INPUT_VIDEO> -c:v libx264 -profile:v baseline -c:a aac -ar 44100 -ac 2 -b:a 128k -movflags faststart output.mp4
```

Are there better conversion parameters I could use to make it universally work with all devices? ( I know that 480x360 h264 works for all devices, but I do not want to give up video quality)

Code that works on certain devices:

```
public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    VideoView videoView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash_screen);
        videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.video_view);

        Uri video = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.splashv4);
        videoView.setVideoURI(video);

        videoView.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                startNextActivity();
            }
        });

        videoView.start();
    }

    private void startNextActivity() {
        if (isFinishing())
            return;
        startActivity(new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class));
        finish();
    }
}
```

Comment: what's the original file format? can you post any code you tried so far?

Comment: original file format is mp4, but the encoding is probably not compatible with all android devices, also updated code (works with Nexus, Pixel, and some others, but not for Pixel XL, Galaxy series, etc @gratienasimbahwe

Answer (score 0):

I would consider using WEBM format rather than MP4. WebM plays in every Android device I have ever encountered.

Comment: how would you suggest I go about converting it? as in what encoding should i use

Comment: If it's just a single file conversion, Firefogg will be the easiest option. Otherwise, try something like 

ffmpeg -i input-file.mp4 -c:v libvpx -crf 10 -b:v 1M -c:a libvorbis output-file.webm

Comment: I tried using webm, but that made the video very choppy on the devices that it works on, and it still wouldnt work on the Pixel 2

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't, take a look at the [recommended media formats](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/media-formats). If the resolution is the problem, you could create another file in 480*360. It's safe to assume that devices which are not able to play an HD video probably have smaller screen. Add a `setOnErrorListener` to your `VideoView` and try to play the video again with the smaller resolution if the first attempt fails. Return `true` in your `OnErrorListener` in order to get rid of the `Can't play this video` dialog.

**EDIT**

I recommend to double check the URI too. According to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40947380/why-uri-parse-does-not-return-valid-image-uri-of-an-image-in-the-drawable-fold), using `android.resource://` is not a good idea.

Comment: I dont think resolution is the problem, as the smaller screen plays it fine (Pixel 2, Nexus), but the Pixel 2 XL does not

Comment: Can you see the error in the logs? Have you tried to remove `-movflags faststart` (that's probably unnecessary if you don't stream the file) ? Are you sure the Uri works on the XL? I would try a different URI based on this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40947380/why-uri-parse-does-not-return-valid-image-uri-of-an-image-in-the-drawable-fold. See `CommonsWare`'s comment